# Sum of unique values in a column

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, unique

I want to get the sum of the unique values in a column per year after satisfying some conditions.

Here is my data from dput:

```
structure(list(key = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("1992_10_18_0", 
"1992_10_18_12", "1992_10_18_18", "1992_10_18_6", "1993_10_18_0", 
"1993_10_18_12", "1993_10_18_18", "1993_10_18_6"), class = "factor"), 
 RR = c(43.25, 43.25, 43.25, 43.25, 43.25, 43.25, 43.25, 43.25, 
 43.25, 43.25, 43.25, 43.25, 43.25, 43.25, 43.25, 43.25), 
 dist = c(1000.23361607017, 694.022935174544, 748.618896699399, 
 812.290633745208, 869.896619169459, 1136.88564181537, 
 1058.59136791648, 
 975.756885299645, 1000.23361607017, 694.022935174544, 
 748.618896699399, 
 812.290633745208, 869.896619169459, 1136.88564181537, 
 1058.59136791648, 
 975.756885299645), Year = c(1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 
 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 
1993L, 1993L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))
```

**What I want:**

There are four columns in the data: key, RR, dist, and Year.

I want to get the sum of RR based on the unique "key" values per year such that the "dist" is less than or equal to 1100.

**What I have so far:**

I am processing multiple files so the script is like this:

```
dat<-read.csv("test_dat.csv",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat2<-dat[which(dat$dist <= 1100),]
dat3<-as.data.frame(cbind(dat2$RR,dat2$Year))
colnames(dat3)<-c("RR","Year")
agg<-aggregate(.~Year,dat3,sum,na.rm=T)

write.csv(agg,file="test.csv",row.names=T)
```

Any idea on how I can do this in R?
I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `dplyr` could be to `filter` the `dist` values less than 1100 and keep only unique values for `key` and `sum` `RR` and `dist` columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  filter(dist <= 1100 & !duplicated(key)) %>%
  summarise(RR = sum(RR), dist = sum(dist))
```

---

To count distinct values, we can use `n_distinct`

```
df %>%
  filter(dist <= 1100) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(n = n_distinct(key))
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer!!!! Actually, I tried using the "distinct" from the dplyr package but gives me incorrect values. Do you know how can I also use that? Maybe as another answer so that I can upvote it.

Comment: @Lyndz if you want to count unique values of `key` for that we can use `n_distinct`. I was confused initially because of  `sum of the unique "key" values`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. What I really want is the sum of the RR per year based on unique key. I am getting an error: Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument.
Calls: %>% ... <Anonymous> -> summarise -> summarise.tbl_df -> summarise_impl
Execution halted

Comment: @Lyndz are you getting error on the same data which you have shared? Works fine for me though. Can you explicitly mention the package name in the call? Must be a problem of masking of functions from other package. Try `df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Year) %>%
  dplyr::filter(dist <= 1100 & !duplicated(key)) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(RR = sum(RR), dist = sum(dist))
`

Comment: I am applying it for a larger data set now, but I still get the same error: I uploaded the file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ey19qnvfkh9me8/Casiguran_proc_tc_induced.csv?dl=0

Comment: Maybe because of the NA?

Comment: ahh..no it is because your `RR` is of type character. Try doing `df %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  filter(dist <= 1100 & !duplicated(key)) %>%
  summarise(RR = sum(as.numeric(RR), na.rm = TRUE)) `

Comment: Should I just ignore this warning message? 1: In evalq(sum(as.numeric(RR), na.rm = TRUE), <environment>) :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: @Lyndz yes, because you have character `NA` in that place. Check `df$RR[1103:1110]` those values are converted to actual `NA` values.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this via the `aggregate` function as you've used, in combination with the function `unique`:

```
agg <- aggregate(key ~ Year, data=subset(dat, dist <= 1100), FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Or, in full context:

```
dat<-read.csv("test_dat.csv",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
agg <- aggregate(key ~ Year, data=subset(dat, dist <= 1100), FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))
write.csv(agg,file="test.csv",row.names=T)
```

In this example, the output generated is:

```
  Year key
1 1992   4
2 1993   4
```